# Автоматическая генерация миниатюр wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

При загрузке изображений и публикации записей миниатюры не создаются.
При попытке получить миниатюру - получаю фулл сайз.

Если запустить:
с консоли **wp media regenerate** - миниатюры **появляются**
плагин Regenerate Thumbnails - миниатюры **появляются**

Как сделать чтобы они генерировались для загруженного изображения **сразу после его загрузки**/публикации поста?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как сделать чтобы они генерировались для загруженного изображения
>   сразу после его загрузки/публикации поста?

По умолчанию генерируется миниатюры, размерами, указанными в настройках миниатюр. Если там нули, то может и не генерироваться.
Коме того размеры могут [пере]определяться плагинами и темой.
Простое выполнение пп [4-6](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B) позволит выявить виновного. Или воспользоваться режимом решения проблем в плагине [health check](https://wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/)

Comment: там кастомные размеры миниатюр, которые добавлены через  add_image_size

Comment: @sinica ну значит при добавлении не вызывается "там"

Comment: Оказалось для админки обнулялись зачем-то миниатюры, ох уж эти гавнокодеры...